# How to get from Split to Vis

Tags: tickets, ferries, croatia, split

I would like to get from Split to Vis on a Monday in high season and I can't work out two things. What are the times of the fastest boat (catamaran?) and do I need to book them in advance or should I just show up? I will be on foot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis_(island)), it appears the only company operating Split-Vis ferries is [Jadrolinija](https://www.jadrolinija.hr/en/)

From the local lines' timetable on their website, are operating *slow* car ferry line 602 (taking 2h20) and *fast* catamaran line 9602 (taking 1h25-1h35)

> do I need to book them in advance or should I just show up?

I do not know for the car ferry, but for the catamaran, their reservation system lists how many seats are left when looking for a crossing.

Looking at answer writing time, for the following week on those catamarans crossings there are always more than 200 seats available, except on Tuesday 25th where there are fewer than 150 seats

Comment: https://www.jadrolinija.hr/en/schedule/ScheduleSearchResults/Index/2331792/2331806/31072023 suggests that 9602 only goes at 6pm on a Monday! Am I reading that wrong?

Comment: @Simd No you're not, it does only goes at 6pm. It's very likely a commuter-heavy way of doing this crossing, which explains the hours [timetable](https://www.jadrolinija.hr/docs/default-source/redovi-plovidbe-i-cijene/-split---milna-(bra%C4%8D)---hvar---vis.pdf?sfvrsn=236eeac7_1). The 602 seems more frequent and more convenient